# Showing that $f: D_1(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \frac{1}{1- \|x\| }$ is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I understand that I need to show that for all $x_0 \in D_1(0)$,

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{1}{1- \|x\| } = \frac{1}{1- \|x_0\| }$$

But I have trouble bounding the denominator,

$$\bigg| \frac{1}{1- \|x\| } - \frac{1}{1- \|x_0\| } \bigg| = \bigg| \frac{\|x\| - \|x_0\|}{(1- \|x\|)(1- \|x_0\|)} \bigg| \stackrel{\text{triangle inequality}}{\leq}  \frac{\|x - x_0\|}{|1-(\|x_0\| + \|x\|) + \|x_0\|\|x\||}$$

Comment: Is $D_1(0)=\{x\in\mathbb R^2:\Vert x\Vert<1\}$?

Comment: If $g:X\to Y$ is continuous  and if $h:Y\to Z$ is continuous then $f(x)=h(g(y))$ is continuous from $X$ to $Z. $ Let $Y=(0,1)$ and $g(x)=1-\|x\|.$  Let $Z=\Bbb R^+ $ and $h(y)=1/y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: drop your last inequality. That is not useful. $|\|x\|-\|x_0\|| \leq \|x-x_0\|$ and $1-\|x\| \geq 1-\|x_0\|-\|x-x_0\|>\frac {1-\|x_0\|} 2$ if $\|x-x_0\|$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: Can I bound $\delta < \frac{1 - \| x_0 \|}{2}$ and then pick $\delta = \frac{(1 - \| x_0 \|)^2}{2}\min\big\{\frac{1 - \| x_0 \|}{2}, \epsilon\big\}$?

Comment: $0<\delta <\frac {\epsilon} 2(1-||x_0\|)^{2}$ will serve the purpose.